# Does the EPD Free distribution use MKL?

Tags: lapack, blas, enthought, intel-mkl, epd-python

According to the Enthought website, the EPD Python distribution uses MKL for numpy and scipy.  Does EPD Free also use MKL?  If not does it use another library for BLAS/LAPACK?  I am using EPD Free 7.3-2

Also, what library does the windows binary installer for numpy that can be found on scipy.org use?

Answer (score 2):

The EPD Free 7.3 installers do not include MKL. The BLAS/LAPACK libraries which they use are ATLAS on Linux & Windows and Accelerate on OSX.

Comment: It's now included in the free version of [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy), which seems to be the replacement for [EPD](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this table](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php), EPD Free 7.3 does *not* include Intel's MKL.

Comment: It's now included in the free version of [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy), which seems to be the replacement for [EPD](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/).